# Programmatically insert files into Dired buffer

Tags: elisp, dired, files

I have a list of file names (with full path) and I want to create a Dired buffer listing this set of files. How would I go about doing that?

**How do I create a Dired buffer from a list of file names?**

Without using external dependencies.

Comment: Please clarify.  Are the strings in your list a) the names of the files you wish to create, or b) the content of the file (the thing for which you have an absolute path)?

Comment: @Dan A list of filenames with absolute paths. Just the filenames.

Comment: Actually, it's hard to understand what you're trying to do.  Could you explain more?  Do these files already exist, or are you really trying to populate a directory with empty files and open up a dired buffer in that directory?

Comment: @Dan You can assume that the files exist. Let's make it simpler: How do I convert a filename string (with path) into an entry in Dired buffer programmatically?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can just use `(find-file your-directory-path)` to get the relevant `dired` buffer (e.g., `(find-file "/tmp/")` will open up your `tmp` directory in a `dired` buffer).

Comment: @Dan No, I want to create a Dired buffer from an arbitrary set of files. For example, Dired+ has a feature that can create a union between Dired buffers. But I just want to have a hint how to do something like that but simpler, hence this question, and continue my way.

Comment: I've edited your question based on what you said in these comments. Feel free to rollback if I got it wrong.

Comment: If you want to ask about file objects in elisp that's an entirely different question, with a very short answer: there aren't any. :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`C-h f dired` tells you the answer.  Just pass to `dired`, as the `DIRNAME` argument, a list that has as its car the Dired buffer name you want (any string) and as cdr the list of file names you want listed in the buffer. Generally, you want to use absolute file names.  For example:

```
(dired (list "My Dired Buffer Name*"     ; The Dired buffer name
             "/usr/foo/file1.el"         ; First file
             "/usr/bar/toto/some-file.c" ; Second file
             "/whatever/directory/"      ; Third is a directory
             "/a/file/somewhere.zzz"))   ; Fourth
```

Depending on your platform, names of any *nonexistent* files and directories you enter might be ignored (not listed), or might raise an error.  The former happens if you use `ls-lisp.el` (e.g. MS Windows).  You can force the use of `ls-lisp` on any platform, if you like (but `ls-lisp` has fewer `ls` options), by doing this:

```
(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil)
(require 'ls-lisp)
```

If you use library [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/dired%2b.el)) then you can interactively choose files and directories to list: just give `dired` a non-positive prefix argument (i.e., <= 0). You are then prompted repeatedly for the directories and file names you want listed.  You can use file-name wildcards (i.e., `*` for globbing), to include the matching files and directories.  Use `C-g` to end inputting.

In other words, instead of listing a single directory, the Dired
buffer can list any number of directories and file names, which can
even belong to different directory trees.

(A non-negative prefix arg (i.e., >= 0) prompts you for the `ls` listing switches.  So a zero prefix arg prompts you for both switches and files/dirs to list: first the `ls` switches and then the files/dirs.)

Comment: Well I want to do it in Elisp, not using command. I just want a simple code snippet that turn a file name (with full path) into an entry in Dired buffer, similar to how I use `(insert ...)` to insert text into a buffer.

Comment: @tudo: `dired` is an elisp function.  Just evaluate this: `(dired '("my-list" "/home/rekado/dev/script.scm" "/home/rekado/another-file"))` and you get a dired buffer containing these files as @Drew wrote.

Comment: @rekado .Thanks. Now I reread the answer correctly it's like what you said. I just want to see an Elisp code snippet like yours, and I thought that Drew gave me a user command answer when I glimpsed it.

Comment: @Drew Please add rekado's example. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Initially I didn't think it would be this simple, when I see [filesets](http://www.emacswiki.org/FileSets). I thought we must make Dired recognize proper file objects for it to work properly.

Comment: @Drew I'm not sure if this is the behavior of Emacs 24.4, but it signals an error when file does not exist.

Comment: @TuDo: You're right. I've edited that. It does not raise an error - it just prints a message (warning). The command continues normally, with that file or dir name ignored.

Comment: @Drew it gave a file error: `(file-error "Reading directory" "no such file or directory" "/usr/foo/file1.el")`.

Comment: @TuDo: Perhaps it depends on your platform. On MS Windows, Emacs uses `ls-lisp.el`, and `ls-lisp-insert-directory` for a non-existent file just calls `(message "%s: doesn't exist or is inaccessible" file)` and then `(ding)`. What code is raising that `file-error` for you?

Comment: @Drew I see. I am using Linux's `ls`, so it signaled an error.

Comment: @TuDo: Try to find out what code is handling the error - e.g., `insert-directory`. You can perhaps tweak the handling of `file-error` so it becomes a no-op. Sounds like this might be good to report as an Emacs bug: there is really no reason (in this context) for the command to fail (IMHO). I'll take a look at vanilla `insert-directory`...

Comment: @TuDo: Seems to be an unhandled error here, in `insert-directory`: `(access-file file "Reading directory")` (and even if that succeeds, it is followed by a call to `error`). You could try wrapping such stuff in `ignore-errors`, but it probably wouldn't be worth it...

Comment: @TuDo: FWIW, I filed an Emacs enhancement request for this (#18836). I doubt that anything will come of it, unless they do decide to let Emacs handle `ls` internally (`ls-lisp.el`), which has been discussed. You can force use of `ls-lisp`, if you want: `(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil) (require 'ls-lisp)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a command to do this when the list of files is in a buffer, with one file per line.

```
(defun dired-virtual-vanilla ()
  (interactive)
  (dired (cons "*Dired*" (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t))))
```