# How can I create a dired buffer listing all open files?

Tags: buffers, dired, files

I have a mechanism for burning items to disc from a `dired` buffer.  Unfortunately,  the file's I've patched are strewn accross the file system.  How can I create a `dired` buffer from all open files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically insert files into Dired buffer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/programmatically-insert-files-into-dired-buffer)

Comment: @Drew I would argue not a duplicate, at least not strictly. This question would simply become 'How do I get a list of all open buffers bound to files?'.

Comment: @Drew Specifically: `(sort (remove nil (mapcar #'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))) #'string<)`

Comment: The information added is that `buffer-list` exists (which I did know) and that `buffer-file-name` returns `nil` when there is no file (which I did not know).  Your proposed duplicate doesn't contain this information or have any need to.

Comment: The only difference is how you come up with the list of files. In that case, this question should be closed and replaced with a question "*How do I get a list of all open files?*"

Comment: @Drew In my experience, trying to make every question as modular as possible is a disadvantage rather than an advantage. It decreases the usefulness with persons who stumble upon this from Google and will never register simply because they Google'd their *use case*.  If I want through every question on TeX.SE and dupe'd questions that had the same conceptual answers, moderation would become a nightmare and the site would plunge into darkness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `dired` command accepts a list of file-names as argument. Just create one and pass to it:

```
(dired
 (cons
  "Open Files"
  (sort (remove nil (mapcar #'buffer-file-name (buffer-list)))
       #'string<)))
```

Comment: I think this misses one file: when you pass a list to dired the first element in that list is taken as the directory name, the rest as the files. How about this: `(dired (cons "*Open Files*" (sort (remove nil (mapcar #'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))) #'string<)))`

Comment: Just a note: this will err if there is a file-associated buffer that has not been saved to disk yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a list of strings, to the dired function, example:

```
(dired '("custom dired" ".emacs.d/init.el" "mydotfiles/.bashrc"))
```

**EDIT**

@Malabarba answer is the best way to go.